# Should routes be nested for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a one-to-many association between `User` and `Occupation` (a user `has_many :occupations`). In the routes file, I did:

```
resources :users do 
   resources :occupations 
end
```

to nest the occupations routes inside the users. Playing around with AJAX requests, I realized it's easier for me to not have the occupations route nested, like this:

```
resources :users

resources :occupations
```

My question is, do I lose (performance, functionality) in any way by not having the routes nested?

**Update:** Aside from losing the users/1/occupations routing. I know that I won't get that if I don't nest the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the performance (if anything, the nested routes might be slightly slower) and just design the routes that make the most sense for your application.